# Complexity of operations in own Matrix class

Tags: c++

I wrote my own Matrix class. I also did a couple of operations to work with the matrix. How to understand the complexity of each operation?
Here are the arithmetic operations:

```
Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T> &other)
    {
        Matrix<T> result(rows, other.cols);
        if (cols == other.rows)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < other.cols; j++)
                {
                    result.data[i * other.cols + j] = 0.0;

                    for (size_t k = 0; k < cols; k++)
                    {
                        result.data[i * other.cols + j] += data[i * cols + k] * other.data[k * other.cols + j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::logic_error("Matrix sizes do not match");
        }
        return result;
    }

    Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> &other)
    {
        Matrix result(rows, cols);
        if (rows == other.rows && cols == other.cols)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] + other.data[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::logic_error("Matrix sizes do not match");
        }
        return result;
    }

    Matrix<T> operator-(const Matrix<T> &other)
    {
        Matrix result(rows, cols);
        if (rows == other.rows && cols == other.cols)
        {

            for (size_t i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] - other.data[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::logic_error("Matrix sizes do not match");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And row and column getters (as I understand them O(1)).

```
[[nodiscard]] size_t getRows() const
    {
        return rows;
    }
    [[nodiscard]] size_t getCols() const
    {
        return cols;
    }
```

What is the complexity of arithmetic operations?

Comment: Recommendation: pick one operation. State what you think the complexity and your reasoning. Turn the question into, "Am I right?" This keeps the question to a single, tightly focused question and shows that you've put some thought into the problem before asking. If it turns out you're right, groovy. Carry on. If not, people will explain where your reasoning is incorrect and this generally produces an answer you (and future askers) will learn more from.

Comment: Regarding the complexity of the addition and multiplication operations, it seems to me that O (n), since we have to run through the entire array and perform actions. Difficulty with multiplication

Answer (score 0):

It's `O(rows * cols * other.cols)` for your 3 nested loops in `operator *` and `O(rows * cols)` for the rest.